# Yellow Spotting Queen Anthurium

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, aroid

Hello I've had this plant for about two months but the spots were on all the leaves at time of purchase. Some things that may be helpful.

- No insects present on plant
- Plant was moved from nursery to my home where it has sat under a grow light and a next to a humidifier, and I've kept it in it's nursery pot
- Potted in a mixture of orchid bark, perlite, and sphagnum moss (from the nursery)
- Watering plant about once a week or whenever it's drying out by soaking it in filtered water and making sure it drains well out of the bottom. I have given it fertilizer twice with watering
- plant sits at a south facing window under grow light
- 4" nursery pot with drain holes
- The plant has continued to grow. It just put out a new leaf(second image) but it already seems like it has very faint spots starting to appear.

Included images below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more details.

Here is the soil
[image: Soil]

Newest leaf with faint spotting
[image: New leaf with faint spotting]

First leaf since bring home from nursery with spotting. This one started with very little faint spotting like the image above.
[image: First leaf spotting]

spotting
[image: spotting]

Close up of spotting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fungus/virus/bacteria that has taken advantage of wet conditions in the root ball to move upstairs, so to speak. Typical signs are

- starts with old growth
- typical end state is a circle of dead tissue surrounded by an area of dying yellow tissue
- sometimes you will see growth "rings" as the fungus/virus/bacteria grows out from the initial area

Most plants can outgrow these kind of infections if the environment is changed to increase drainage or decrease the amount of water.

The soil mix you are using looks right as the sphagnum moss retains water while keeping air spaces.  The problem is that organic matter breaks down and compacts over time.

My recommendations:

- move to higher light, bright indirect light
- consider repotting with a more porous mix  (perhaps an orchid mix?)
- consider your watering schedule and reduce if this could be an issue
- don't let the plant sit in water

Comment: Thank you. I was concerned that it was bacteria, but the store that sold it originally said it wasn't. Thank you for the help.